# Node.js: Removing users in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i'm having problems in removing users in Socket.IO, upon their browser close the `user` in the array `users[]` is not removed and not updated and i would like also to update the users in the client side. Can you help me remove user programmatically? Here is my code guys, i hope you can help me with my code provided below. I've already surfed the net on how to remove users but i can't really make it work. Thanks in advance guys.

Here is my **server.js**:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var publish = redis.createClient();
var subscribe = redis.createClient();

server.listen(8080);

var users = [];
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('adduser', function (user) {
    users[user] = user;
    console.log(users);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function (user) {
    delete users[user] = user;
    io.sockets.emit('update', user);

    // delete users[user] = users;
    // socket.emit('update', users);
    console.log(users)
  });

  socket.on('update', function () {
    users[user] = user;
    console.log('Current users: ', users);
  });
});
```

Here is my **client.html**:

```
<html>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
  });
</script>

<div style="float:left;width:150px;border-right:2px solid black;height:510px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;text-align:center;">
    <b>Users</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Thanks again guys, i hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server-side `disconnect` event isn't going to have a `user` variable in its callback, so you are effectively using `delete users[null]`. Instead, you should be storing the `user` variable in the socket-specific data store, like so:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen();
var users = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('adduser', function(user) {
    socket.set('username', user, function() {
      users[user] = user;
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socket.get('username', function(err, user) {
      delete users[user];
      io.sockets.emit('update', users);
    });
  });
});
```

When the socket disconnects, you can then find its associated `user` variable, and then delete it.

Comment: Well it worked! Thanks @hexcyanide! I missed `socket.user = user` before `users[user] = user`. This code also works `socket.on('adduser', function (user) {
  socket.user = user;
  users[user] = user;
  console.log(users);
 });`